# time limit exceeded C++

Tags: c++

Problem:

You are given a string S and N queries. Each query is defined by two integers - Li and Pi. Count the number of strings of the length Li that occur exactly Pi times (as the consecutive substrings) in the string S.

[C++ code IDEONE](https://ideone.com/UuAkJk)

//COMMENT

```
int main()
{
    /*
    ######INPUT
    s = mynameispujanshahandmybrothersnameischintanshah
    1
    4 2

    ########OUTPUT
    name
    amei
    meis
    ansh
    nsha
    shah
    */
string s;
int q,l,p;
int counter =0;
cin>>s;
//cin>>q;
scanf("%d",&q);
for(int i=0;s[i]!='\0';i++)
   {
   counter++;
   }
while(q--)
{
    scanf("%d",&l);
scanf("%d",&p);
//cin>>l>>p;
int cnt =0;
//UNCOMMENT
string ss,ss1;

//above is initialization
for(int i=0;i<=counter-l;i++){
    //COMMENT
    ss=s.substr(i,l);
   // ss = mysubstr(s,i,l);
    int tot = 0;
    for(int j=0;j<=counter-l;j++){
      ss1 = s.substr(j,l);
      if(ss==ss1){
        if(j<i)
        {
            cout << ss1 << "\n";
           // printf("%s\n", ss1);

            break;
        }

        else
            tot++;
      }
    }
    if(tot==p)
        cnt++;
}

}
return 0;
}
```

How do I overcome Time Limit Exceeded for my problem?

Comment: Come up with a smarter algorithm.  Most of the problems you find on quiz/competition type sites are not meant to be solved by brute force.

Comment: Can you help me optimize it? I tried using scanf printf instead of cin cout, It still gives TLE error

Comment: You just posted this question, and reposted with a new account... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45384842/substring-query-count-no-of-length-l-occuring-p-times

Comment: @guest789 You didn't even talk about how long the time limit is and how large the input can be.

Comment: input can be max 1000 characters

Comment: Then how many queries?

Comment: Input
The first line of input contains the string S.

The second line of input contains the integer N - the number of queries.

Then there are N lines, the i-th one contains numbers Li and Pi for the i-th query.

Comment: So how large the "N" can be!!!

Comment: only single string query at one time

Comment: But as you're talking about Time Limited Exceeded, I believe that you're coding on a website that automatically judge your code, which generally consider the overall time consumption only. Anyway, take a look at the answer I posted. I think it is efficient enough for strings 1000 chars long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can take a look at [this](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/12919) for calculating an integer hash of an arbitrary substring of a given string in constant time.

Then the solution is:

Calculate hashes of all substring of length `L`, and count them using a `map`(or some similar data structure) because you can use the integer hashes to represent a substring.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you will get time limit, your algorithm run with O(n^2) complexity,
where you do tons of string comparison. And by replacing cin with scanf you literally change nothing.

This problem can be easily solved with O(n) complexity by simple iteration over
input string once, and storing all the substring as keys in `std::map<string, int>` container.

Comment: I don't think so, map will still compare the strings, and requires O(n log n) time for each insertion.

Comment: Oh, yes, with map it will not be O(n). In map it will be It will O(log n) for insertion, overall O(n log n), but still much better then O(n^2)

Comment: No, map have to compare the key O(log n) times on insertion. So it you use some `map<int, int>`, the insertion time is O(log n). But for strings, comparing two strings takes O(n), so O(n log n) for one insertion and overall O(n^2 log n).